# Blank row in table after LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I'm uploading a large amount of data from a CSV (I'm doing it via MySQL Workbench):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/development/mydoc.csv' INTO TABLE mydatabase.mytable CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r';
```

However, I'm noticing that it keeps adding an empty line full of nulls/zeros after the last record. I'm guessing it's because of the "LINES TERMINATED" command. However, I need that to load the data in correctly.

Is there some way around this / some better SQL to avoid the blank row in the table?

Comment: What do you mean by "adding an empty line"? Is it adding a line to the file, or adding a row to the table? The LINES TERMINATED command only specifies the layout of the incoming file, it doesn't cause anything to be created that I'm aware of.

Comment: Check the CSV file to make sure there are no blank lines at the end of the file. If there was one empty line at the end it could cause this.

Comment: @brygdesk: the empty row is added to the table.
@Ike Walker: There's no blank lines in the CSV. It's something to do with that command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a newline/CR character at the END of the last line, the load command will try to load another record. But because there is no data after the last newline/CR, all columns are null.

Comment: @YJelton: Thanks, that's more or less what I figured out. However, if I remove it, the data doesn't get entered into rows, but rather crammed into a single row in a weird way. Is there some alternative to the new line?

Comment: It imports a single row if you remove only the *last* newline/CR character? Odd. You could try creating a file with a different delimiter for the lines terminated by, such as the pipe (|) character.